# 405 HTTP error after being redirected from payment gateway

Tags: reactjs, redirect, server, payment-gateway, paytabs

[image]

we are using Vercel for making development fast .
in our react app , after payment page when payment redirect to our given url it gives 405 http error, how can we handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem , it is coming from PayTabs's side
followings are the logic they are handling wrong:

[image]

1. when nothing is received from callback url , they should not redirect us with given redirect url
2. when we are giving an invalid callback url it make a GET request to given redirect url
3. when we are giving an valid callback url which returns 200 to them it make a POST request to given redirect url which is not supported by browser.

Comment: Hi, I came across the same issue. How do I handle no. 3 scenario where the browser does not support a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when your page does not use next js serverside rendering. I had same issue but solved it by converting the page from a static page to a server rendered page using getServerSideProps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).